# c++ why programs reads only first value

Tags: c++

program should read numbers from data.txt file and then print them, but prints only first value good, all other values are the same -9.25596e+061

```
const char CDfv[] = "Data.txt";
const int cmax = 1000;
//---------------------------------------------------------
void read_print_data (double A[], int& x);
//--------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    ofstream fr;
    double A[cmax];
    int x;
    ifstream fv ("Data.txt");
    read_print_data(A,x);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void read_print_data (double A[], int& x)
{
    ifstream fd(CDfv);
    fd >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        fd >> A[i];
        cout << i + 1 << "   " << A[i] << endl;
        fd.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Why have you closed fd `fd.close();` inside the for-loop? You should have closed it out of for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the stream prematurely, You need to move

```
 fd.close();
```

to be outside the loop.

So the code should look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (fd >> A[i]) {
        cout << i + 1 << "   " << A[i] << endl;
    } else {
       // Error has occurred 
    }
}
fd.close();
```